# Android : Mute sound and vibration for all notifications except voice call

Tags: android, audio, notifications, android-vibration, vibration

I am trying to mute `sound` and `vibration` for all Notifications. For that, I used below code

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Using that all call(Normal call, WhatsApp call etc...) sounds muted successfully but I want to mute sound and vibrations only for Notifications not for call.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope you will get answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25717407/1318946

Comment: I think it only block Notification of particular that application, It can not mute all the other notifications..anyway thanks for help