# "App is displaying over other apps" notification

Tags: android, android-8.1-oreo

My app is displaying content over other apps. Everything works after setting

```
ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION
```

In Android 8.1 however there is annoying notification "App is displaying over other apps", which can be turned off by user. (Messenger in this case is just an example).

[image]

This intent opens the settings screen and allows to switch this notification off:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", "android");
startActivity(intent);
```

**But before that I want to programmatically check the current state of this switch.**  **Is it possible?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577682/android-development-disable-show-notification-programmatically-with-root-perm

Comment: No, this is a system notification, not application, also it is new in Android 8+.